# express.js - How can I handle API calls differently based on the page from which they have been called?

Tags: node.js, express

I am a newbie to node and express and I will break the question into 2 steps to better explain what I need.

I am using node and express to build a server with some APIs. I am serving the HTML with:

```
let publicPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public');
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    myLogger.error(err);
    res.status(err.statusCode).json(err);
});
app.listen(PORT, () => { myLogger.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`); });
```

**First step:**

I would like my app to serve the same HTML ('index.html') on different pages, e.g.:

```
localhost:3000/example1
localhost:3000/example2
localhost:3000/example3
```

I am able to do this with:

```
app.use('/example1', express.static(publicPath));
```

and so on and so forth for the other examples. However, I am using [jstreetable](https://github.com/adamjimenez/jstree-table) on the front-end (that is not available on a CDN AFAIK), so I had to download it to node_modules and include it in the HTML with:

```
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')));

<script src="node_modules/jstree-table/jstreetable.js"></script>
```

Now, when I access the server through one of the URLs above (e.g. 'localhost:3000/example1'), I get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/example1/node_modules/jstree-table/jstreetable.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

**Question**: How can I keep the app pointing to the node_modules folder, keeping the path as the following?

```
http://localhost:3000/node_modules/jstree-table/jstreetable.js
```

so that it points to the correct path.

**Second step:**

I have several APIs defined as:

server.js

```
app.use('/api/forge', require('./routes/datamanagement'));
```

/routes/datamanagement.js

```
router.get('/datamanagement', async (req, res) => {
    ...code here...
}
```

**Question:** How can I have the user access this API through the page localhost:3000/example1, making API calls through:

```
localhost:3000/example1/api/forge/datamanagement
```

and also have the API function handle the request based on the page from which it has been called? (e.g. handle it differently if the call is made from 'localhost:3000/example1' or 'localhost:3000/example2')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first question can be solved by using an absolute path, eg

```html
<script src="/node_modules/jstree-table/jstreetable.js"></script>
```

However, I wouldn't advise exposing the entire `node_modules` folder publicly.

Instead, I would only expose the paths that are required. Eg

```js
app.use("/libs/jstree-table", express.static(
  path.join(__dirname, "node_modules", "jstree-table")));
```

and

```html
<script src="/libs/jstree-table/jstreetable.js"></script>
```

---

For your second question, you can use an array of paths when attaching your routes.

For example

```js
const paths = ["/example1", "/example2", "/example3"];

app.use(paths, express.static(publicPath));
app.use(paths.map(path => `${path}/api/forge`), require('./routes/datamanagement'));
```

In your route handlers you can determine the path using [req.baseUrl](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.baseUrl)

```js
const basePath = req.baseUrl.split("/")[1]; // example1, example2, etc
```

To make generic requests from your prefixed URLs, you can use something like this

```js
fetch(location.pathname + "/api/forge/datamanagement")
```

Comment: Thanks! First part worked like a charm.

Second part as well, except for the final retrieval of the base url. The baseUrl of the request only provides me the string used to call the API, in this example '/api/forge'. The array of rawHeaders of the request have what I'm looking for (the 'http://localhost:3000/example1'), and I could parse them to identify the right header and retrieve it, but it doesn't seem like a very elegant solution.

Is there any other way I can retrieve this 'example1'?

Comment: If it helps, I'm calling the API with
'const res = await fetch('/api/forge/datamanagement');'
on the frontend.

Comment: @TiagoPedro that's odd. The documentation for `req.baseUrl` says it should include where the router was mounted. Try using `req.path` instead (I'll update my answer)

Comment: @TiagoPedro I've added an example of how you can prefix your `fetch()` requests with the current page path

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is working now. Adding the `location.pathname` to the `fetch` gets the whole path on the `req.baseUrl`, except for the host path. Now I am getting `/example1/api/forge/datamanagement` which is exactly what I was looking for.
Out of curiosity, is there a workable approach by defining the routes on the server as `app.use('/:exampleid/api/forge', require('./routes/datamanagement')`?

Comment: Yep, that could probably work. It wasn't clear from your question how dynamic it needed to be

Comment: It doesn't need to be highly dynamic as I control the "examples". The last question was just out of curiosity and elegance.